# PHP Fatal error not reproducible in an identical environment

Tags: php

I have two environments, running the same stack, that give different PHPUnit test results.

In my vagrant based environment, our PHPUnit test suite passes with no issues.

In my VPS based environment, we're seeing the following php fatal error:

```
PHPUnit 5.5.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.......................................S.S.....PHP Fatal error:  
Class Mock\Product\Promotion\DataProviderMock contains 5 abstract methods 
and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the 
remaining methods (Olive\Product\Promotion\DataProviderInterface::hasPromotion, Olive\Product\Promotion\DataProviderInterface::isSticky, Olive\Product\Promotion\DataProviderInterface::getValuePromotion, ...) 
in /tmp/popeye/olive/tests/mock/Mock/Product/Promotion/ProviderMock.php on line 11
```

The fix is simple (implement the methods in the class), however before making the fix I would like to understand why the behavior is different in the two environments.

I assume the difference in the two environments is somewhere in my PHP configuration.

I have checked that there are no differences in the environments in the output between `php-config` or `php composer.phar show  -t`.

There are some differences between the output of `php -i` which *might* be related.

Here is a diff of `php -i` with the vagrant environment (which does not see the error) on the left and the VPS environment (which does see the error) on the right:

```
$ diff php-i.vagrant php-i.vps
4c4
< System => Linux vagrant-box 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64
---
> System => Linux staging-01 4.4.0-81-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 08:17:06 UTC 2017 x86_64
109c108
< apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
---
> apc.shm_size => 192M => 192M
112c111
< apc.ttl => 0 => 0
---
> apc.ttl => 86400 => 86400
144,145c143,144
< display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
< display_startup_errors => On => On
---
> display_errors => Off => Off
> display_startup_errors => Off => Off
154c153
< error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
---
> error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
746c745
< opcache.fast_shutdown => 0 => 0
---
> opcache.fast_shutdown => 1 => 1
754c753
< opcache.interned_strings_buffer => 4 => 4
---
> opcache.interned_strings_buffer => 16 => 16
757c756
< opcache.max_accelerated_files => 2000 => 2000
---
> opcache.max_accelerated_files => 16229 => 16229
760c759
< opcache.memory_consumption => 64 => 64
---
> opcache.memory_consumption => 192 => 192
771c770
< opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On
---
> opcache.validate_timestamps => Off => Off
793c792
```

Are there any PHP gurus reading this who might be able to explain why we see this error in only one environment?

Many thanks!

Comment: This seems potentially better suited to https://serverfault.com/ since it's dealing with the intricacies of configuring PHP, good luck though

Comment: If you can write a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem, at a minimum, in your vagrant environment, that might be something. As it is, it's pretty difficult for anyone to help you, sight unseen.

Comment: I've been googling that error, and I can't find any configuration options that would affect it, other than whether error reporting is enabled.

Comment: You have different `error_reporting` settings in the two environments.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's due to the difference in one of these settings related to errors:

```
144,145c143,144
< display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
< display_startup_errors => On => On
---
> display_errors => Off => Off
> display_startup_errors => Off => Off
154c153
< error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
---
> error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
```

Comment: Thanks, I suspect you could be correct. I will focus my investigations on those configuration options.